# android admob Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<uO>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError eror

Tags: android, admob

I get this error when I do not get admob ads coming out at any moment.

What is the workaround?

In my memory, the ad first appeared normally, but not from any moment.

The Android versions of the devices tested were 8.0.0, 8.1.0.

```
MainActivity.java:432 => MobileAds.initialize("~");
```

I checked both the App ID and the Unit ID.

```html
-- I/zygote64: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<uO>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/TracingController;
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:128)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:402)
-- I/zygote64:     at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:194)
-- I/zygote64:     at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2530)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2525)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2590)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:4865)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:5040)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:597)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:643)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:588)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:571)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:558)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:548)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.<init>(com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.au, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.av, java.lang.String, boolean, nb, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bo, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.v, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):1)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.q.call() ((null):4)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bp.a(java.util.concurrent.Callable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):19)
-- I/zygote64:     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.i com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.av, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, nb, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bo, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.v, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):7)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.p.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, nb) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):5)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.run() ((null):17)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ad.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):4)
-- I/zygote64:     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ap com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.x.a(nb) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):13)
-- I/zygote64:     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.al com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.x.a() (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):23)
-- I/zygote64:     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.b.b(java.lang.Object) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):7)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, boolean, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.e, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):28)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):4)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.z.a(java.lang.String, xl) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):53)
-- I/zygote64:     at boolean com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.be.a(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):32)
-- I/zygote64:     at boolean og.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):4)
-- I/zygote64:     at boolean android.os.Binder.transact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (Binder.java:635)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzew.zza(int, android.os.Parcel) ((null):20)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzye.zza(java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper) ((null):26)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzc.zza(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzf) ((null):26)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds$Settings) ((null):5)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) ((null):1)
-- I/zygote64:     at void --.MainActivity.setAdmob() (MainActivity.java:432)
-- I/zygote64:     at void --.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:123)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7258)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7249)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1221)
-- I/zygote64:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2927)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3059)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1724)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7002)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:441)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
-- I/zygote64: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.TracingController" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.chrome-BKniZXieiVCfB0bUvlePJA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-BKniZXieiVCfB0bUvlePJA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.android.chrome-BKniZXieiVCfB0bUvlePJA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:-2)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.forName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Class.java:453)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewProviderClass(java.lang.ClassLoader) (WebViewFactory.java:128)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass() (WebViewFactory.java:402)
-- I/zygote64:     at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider() (WebViewFactory.java:194)
-- I/zygote64:     at android.webkit.WebViewFactoryProvider android.webkit.WebView.getFactory() (WebView.java:2530)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated() (WebView.java:2525)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(int) (WebView.java:2590)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context) (View.java:4865)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (View.java:5040)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (ViewGroup.java:597)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:643)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:588)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:571)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:558)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context) (WebView.java:548)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.<init>(com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.au, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.av, java.lang.String, boolean, nb, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bo, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.v, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):1)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.q.call() ((null):4)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bp.a(java.util.concurrent.Callable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):19)
-- I/zygote64:     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.i com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.o.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.av, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, nb, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.csi.l, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.bo, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.v, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.clearcut.a) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):7)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.p.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, nb) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):5)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.y.run() ((null):17)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ad.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):4)
-- I/zygote64:     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ap com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.x.a(nb) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):13)
-- I/zygote64:     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.al com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.x.a() (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):23)
-- I/zygote64:     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.x com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.b.b(java.lang.Object) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):7)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, boolean, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.e, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):28)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ac.a(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.client.p, java.lang.String, java.lang.Runnable) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):4)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.z.a(java.lang.String, xl) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):53)
-- I/zygote64:     at boolean com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.be.a(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):32)
-- I/zygote64:     at boolean og.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14574048@14.5.74 (040400-219897028):4)
-- I/zygote64:     at boolean android.os.Binder.transact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (Binder.java:635)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzew.zza(int, android.os.Parcel) ((null):20)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzye.zza(java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper) ((null):26)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzc.zza(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzf) ((null):26)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds$Settings) ((null):5)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(android.content.Context, java.lang.String) ((null):1)
-- I/zygote64:     at void --.MainActivity.setAdmob() (MainActivity.java:432)
-- I/zygote64:     at void --.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:123)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7258)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7249)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1221)
-- I/zygote64:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2927)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3059)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1724)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
-- I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7002)
-- I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:441)
-- I/zygote64:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

build.gradle file.

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "--"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}
```

Comment: What is your main question? Also consider of reading [ask].

Comment: target and compile sdk version should be same and updated. You can set 26 sdk version and try again.